# Change UINavigationbar color for "More" tab?

Tags: ios, ios4, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

I'm currently using

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

to change the color of my UINavigationBars in my iOS application. However my app now has so many tab bar items it uses Apple's default "More" controller to manage the extra items. Unfortunately, I can't seem to work out how to change the color of the "More" UINavigationBar. Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: Found you can do it - see http://cduu.wordpress.com/2010/08/27/uinavigationbar-color-of-more-tab/
 for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build a custom toolbar, just use a custom view for your UIBarButtonItem.  For an example of this, check out

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AddMusic/Listings/Classes_MainViewController_m.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008845-Classes_MainViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

On that page, look in the -handle_NowPlayingItemChanged: method where it creates a UIBarButtonItem with a UIButton as its custom view.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done. you might want to build a custom "toolbar" if you want that kind of control.

Comment: Actually, it can. Just found this post (http://snaglz.wordpress.com/2010/08/27/uinavigationbar-color-of-more-tab/) where you can use rootController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; Thanks anyway though.