# iPhone - How to set custom color in the "More" item's navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, tintcolor

G'day All

This is a small detail but it does affect the professional finish of my app.

My app follows the pattern of a tab bar with a navigation bar on each tab with more than 5 tabs hence a "More" item. I have a custom tint applied to the navigation bar but I haven't been able to find a way to access the navigation bar of the "More" item to set the tint on that. Can anyone tell me how?

Update...

Following the suggestion of a category on `UINavigationBar` I used this code...

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBar_Additions)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.862745098039216
                                     green:0.568627450980392
                                      blue:0.098039215686275
                                     alpha:1];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [color CGColor]));
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    [self setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    [self setTintColor:color];
}

@end
```

Aside from Apple's warning (for reasons that seem to make sense to me) about not overriding hidden methods like this it also loses the gradient on the `UINavigationBar` & I'd rather keep that which my current approach of setting the tint in `viewDidLoad` does.

Any suggestions as to how I can have my cake & eat it too.

TIA, Pedro :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change UINavigationbar color for "More" tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139719/change-uinavigationbar-color-for-more-tab)

Comment: Thanks to Jeff Kelley I have this solved. It's a small thing in some ways but it goes a way to a nice professional finish to my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been covered [before on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139719/change-uinavigationbar-color-for-more-tab), which points to [this blog](http://snaglz.wordpress.com/2010/08/27/uinavigationbar-color-of-more-tab/), but the answer is to do the following:

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor =
[UIColor orangeColor];
```

Comment: Oh that is a thing of great beauty, thank you :) Pity I didn't find that earlier post when I went looking before asking.

Comment: This tints everything. What if you just want the background color tinted?

Answer (score 1):

Add a category to UINavigationBar and override -drawRect:? (You can then do fun things like drawing an image instead...)

Comment: That's not how you override `-drawRect:` sensibly; it generally involves something some people call "method swizzling" (traditionally via a call to `method_exchangeImplementations()`); you need to do this because super-calling calls the superclass implementation, not the original implementation in the class. I was thinking you could just set the tint color and then call the original implementation.